# select multiple with multiple selected options returns to many options

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I have a form with 2 select multiple.
I get the data with 2 functions.
The problem is if the client have multiple selected options.
I get everything returned as many times as the client has selected values.

If there is 5 options where 1 is selected = I get 5 options and one of them selected.
If there is 5 options where 2 are selected = I get 10 options (2 of each") and one is selected.

If I try to add "GROUP BY NAME" in the SELECT I get the correct options but only one selected.

Can you please tell me what I'm missing?

    `function GetTheArea() {`

```
include 'dbconn.php';
$client_id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT applicant_location.APPLICANT, applicant_location.LOCATION, 
location.NAME, location.LOCATION_ID FROM applicant_location , location WHERE 
applicant_location.APPLICANT = $client_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row["LOCATION_ID"] === $row["LOCATION"]) {
        $usedornot = "selected=\"selected\"";
    echo "<option value=\"" . $row["LOCATION_ID"]."\" 
".$usedornot.">".$row["NAME"]."</option>";
} else {
    echo "<option value=\"" . $row["LOCATION_ID"]."\">".$row["NAME"]."
</option>";
  }
 }
}
function GetTheProf() {
    include 'dbconn.php';
    $client_id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT applicant_profession.APPLICANT, 
applicant_profession.PROFESSION, profession.`NAME`, profession.PROFESSION_ID 
FROM applicant_profession , profession WHERE applicant_profession.APPLICANT = $client_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row["PROFESSION"] === $row["PROFESSION_ID"]) {
        $usedornot = "selected=\"selected\"";
    echo "<option value=\"" . $row["PROFESSION_ID"]."\" 
".$usedornot.">".$row["NAME"]."</option>";
} else {
    echo "<option value=\"" . $row["PROFESSION_ID"]."\">".$row["NAME"]."
</option>";
  }
 }
}
```

```
<select name="LOCATION[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
<?php GetTheArea(); ?>
```

Comment: You're doing an implicit CROSS JOIN here, so that result is to be expected ... suggest you go do some reading up on what other types of JOIN there are, and figure out which one might be more appropriate to get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that there was something like that.
The problem is that I tried with the following:
SELECT APPLICANT, LOCATION, NAME, LOCATION_ID
FROM applicant_location
JOIN location
on applicant_location.LOCATION = location.LOCATION_ID
WHERE applicant_location.APPLICANT = $client_id
But this just gave me the selected values. I need all values and add "selected" to some of them. Any info would be most appreciated.